# bind function when command s is pressed (OSX)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a couple of keypress scripts but I need a key binding in Chrome and Safari for command key and s (like saving files in desktop applications). Does anybody know about such a script or plugin?
jquery is in place but pure JavaScript solutions are also welcome!

thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+1',function (evt){  
  setTimeout("console.log('ctrl+1')",50);return false;
});
```

is fine.
To determine what keys will fire which event i recommend strongly [this w3.org test page](http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html).

Comment: this is not correct bud.. well at least does not answer OP's question

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Well... I wanted something like this soo I wrote my own..**

```
  function setAppleSSave(form) {
    var lastKey;
    $(window).bind('keydown',function(e){
      if( lastKey && (lastKey == 91 && e.keyCode == 83) || (lastKey == 83 && e.keyCode == 91) ){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(form).submit();
        return false;
      }
      lastKey = e.keyCode;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

this works fine for me any recommendations? I'm not a good JavaScripter :)

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var last_key = 0;
var code_meta_key = 91;
var code_s = 83;

$(document).keydown(function(event){ 

  if (last_key == 91 && event.keyCode == 83) {
    setTimeout("console.log('boom')",50);
    return false;
  }

  last_key = (event.keyCode == 91) ? 91 : 0;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who came for a lightweight and straightforward way to get the job done, here it is :

```
$(window).keydown(function (e){
    if (e.metaKey && e.keyCode == 83) {
        yourFunction();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```